# How valid is this Stacking Model (input features to weak learners are different)?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, naive-bayes, k-nearest-neighbour, stacking

I have a set of features with **6 of them being categorical, 1 continuous and 2 textual in type**.
I have to predict the labels ( 10 in number) for them. 
I tried applying several models and came to a conclusion that one predictive model is not enough to get the required efficiency. So I applied a stacking model using **Random Forest, K- Nearest Neighbors and Multinomial Naive Bayes algorithms.**

Since RF and KNN can take only integer/float values, I was able to **encode my 6 categorical features** to give as input.
But as for the 2 text fields, i had to use NLP libraries(nltk) in python and apply Naive Bayes to get some predictions. However, it has less efficiency.
Nonetheless, I took the predictions of all of the above three models and fed it to a third model (again RF or KNN). The prediction outputs on the test set looks good with up to 98% accuracy score.

So, in short, I am sending **different** features as inputs to the weak learners, and then combining them for input to the stronger model. Is this  a valid way of stacking?

[image]

Comment: None of these models are weak learners IMO. Also, applying RF to only 3 inputs seems a bit odd to me.

Answer (score 0):

You do NOT want to train your layer 1 models with `complete data` since that will leak information to layer 2 model.

You should be doing train-test split or k-fold to more accurately test your model. You can check here for more details about how to apply stacking: http://blog.kaggle.com/2016/12/27/a-kagglers-guide-to-model-stacking-in-practice/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have corrected my data leakage problem. But now the accuracy score for test data is 57% while it remains 98% for train data (even with k-folds). The accuracy score is further decreasing for test data in layer 2 model, when it is expected to improve. Do you have any idea why this happening? Why is the model not able to learn?